# Postman: receiving syntax errors from postman POST request

Tags: json, post, postman

```
{
    "order": {
        "operationTimes": {
            "start": "",
            "end": ""
        },
        "forCustomer": "87778",
        "type": "8787",
        "stand": "",
        "plannedStartAt": "",
        "begin": {
            "number": "9445",
            "destination": "8787",
            "suffix": "",
            "originDate": "21\/02\/2021",
            "isNew": true,
            "origin": "989898",
            "existingId": "",
            "company": "98998"
        },
        "private": false,
        "loc": "",
        "types": "test",
        "date": "21\/02\/2021",
        "transactionType": "",
        "testSupplier": "88881d335b647351068b0000",
        "cust": "343434"
    },
    "forNew": false
}
```

However, when I post this as raw in Postman, I'm getting the following syntax error:

`Failed to parse data (org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 650 [character 45 line 26]`

This points to the `testSupplier` line but I cannot see where I'm missing anything here.I don't want to be closing the object with `}` at this point as I have more properties which are part of the `order` object. And I already have a `,`. Obviously this error is preventing the full body from posting and therefore I am receiving a 400 response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Update:

When I check the call through Charles proxy, this is what is actually being posted in the body:

```
{
    "fuelOrder": {
        "operationTimes": {
            "onBlocksAtScheduled": "",
            "offBlocksAtScheduled": ""
        },
        "forCustomer": "3255",
        "fuelType": "23523",
        "stand": "",
        "plannedStartAt": "",
        "outbound": {
            "number": "9445",
            "destination": "235235",
            "suffix": "",
            "originDate": "21\/02\/2021",
            "isNew": true,
            "origin": "235235",
            "existingId": "",
            "airline": "52323523"
        },
        "privateFlight": false,
        "terminal": "",
        "type": "ref",
        "date": "21\/02\/2021",
        "transactionType": "",
        "fuelSupplier": "23523"
```

So it is not posting anything after `fuelSupplier`

This is how the error is showing in Charles

[image]

Comment: Key `type` is there twice. That's of course valid JSON, but might be a problem in JSON library used on the server side.

Comment: Thanks - in fact that's just my mistake from the post - I changed some of the key names but in the actual post there are no duplicate keys (just changed it on the question)

Comment: have you selected json from the dropdown ?

Comment: yes i have - just for clarity i added an image of the actual request above with real param names and the settings selected

Comment: your body in the question is valid https://jsonlint.com/ you can validate in this site also, even i n postman there is no error meaning it is valid. Talk to devloper of service they might be ignoring the empty value of transactionType

Comment: is the error in response ? could you show the error scrreenshot also

Comment: see added screenshot and details above

Comment: the weird thing is I've successfully posted this body via an iOS app that I'm working on. In fact, I just copy and pasted the JSON from a successful POST request and added it into the body of the request in postman. I just cannot figure out why this is failing via postman...

Comment: "fuelSupplier": "23523" doesn have an ending , or } , this is the full body , ? the first one is valid second one is not valid